# Changing the sitemap node title

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a "one for all" 'ProductsList.aspx' which loads all different types of products based on the 'CategoryId' querystring send to it, hence if a user clicks 'Basketball' link, I need the sitemap title in the 'ProductList.aspx' to write 'Basketball'.

I tried

```
 SiteMap.CurrentNode.ReadOnly = false;
 SiteMap.CurrentNode.Title = "Basketball";
```

in the page_load of 'ProductList.aspx' but apparently it doesn't work. Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check the following url,

http://forums.asp.net/t/1590425.aspx

Hope this helps....